# Hacer match con un string y una regex en C#

Tags: c#, regex

¿Cómo puedo hacer match para saber sí cumple mi variable `string` con la expresión regular en C#? Esta es la expresión regular:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");
```

Lo que he visto es que se puede hacer con `StreamReader` pero no encuentro una forma de hacerlo desde un `string` Nota: La expresión regular es para saber si esta dentro del rango una dirección `IP`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el metodo .IsMatch()

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");
if (reg.IsMatch("127.0.0.1"))
 {
 Console.writeln("Es IP");
 }
```